# Not sure I'm using methods right in java :/

Tags: java

Hiii.
We just started learning about methods in class.We were supposed to write a program that adds and subtracts any 2 integers.It should use a method called validateMe(which I've used) that accepts the user input value and checks if its int data type or not.If its not,the method should display an error msg and keep asking for user input.If it's right,the program should continue.
I have 2 questions regarding my program:

1. My program works okay.The method is being used.But I'm just concerned whether it contains some extra code.Maybe there's something I can omit and make the program shorter.I'm just concerned whether this is the most efficient way of doing it.
2. As you can see in the comments,I've added a variable 'error'.This is supposed to increment by 1 each time the user makes a mistake.I should have a running total of the no. of errors made.This part of my program is not working.
   Any help would be appreciated.
   Thanks.

   ```
   import java.util.*;

   public class Methods {

       public static void main(String[]args){
           //int errors=1;
           for(int d=1;d>0;d++)
           {
               Scanner a=new Scanner(System.in);
               System.out.println("Please enter whole number: ");
               double num1=a.nextDouble();

               Scanner b=new Scanner(System.in);
               System.out.println("Please enter whole number: ");
               double num2=b.nextDouble();

               if(Math.floor(num1)!=num1 || Math.floor(num2)!=num2)
               {
                   validateMe();
                   //errors=errors+1;
                   //System.out.println(errors);
               }
               else 
               {
                   System.out.println("Great job!");
                   System.out.println("Addition: "+(num1+num2));
                   System.out.println("Subtraction: "+(num1-num2));
               }
           }
       }

       public static void validateMe(){
           //int errors=1;
           System.out.println("Sorry!Try again.");
           //errors=errors+1;
           //System.out.println("Number of errors: "+errors);

           Scanner a=new Scanner(System.in);
           System.out.println("Please enter whole number: ");
           double num1=a.nextDouble();

           Scanner b=new Scanner(System.in);
           System.out.println("Please enter whole number: ");
           double num2=b.nextDouble();

           if(Math.floor(num1)!=num1 || Math.floor(num2)!=num2)
           {
               validateMe();

               //errors=errors+1;
               //System.out.println("Number of errors: "+errors);

           }
           else 
           {
               System.out.println("Great job!");
               System.out.println("Addition: "+(num1+num2));
               System.out.println("Subtraction: "+(num1-num2));
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Why do you have two scanner objects a and b? You only need one as far as i can tell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what the expected behavior is, but you are clearly redefining the **errors** variable and reassigning the value 1 every time the method is called. This means that even if you get 10 errors, your variable will never hold a value of 10 because it keeps being reset.

If you were trying to keep a total count of all errors across the entire duration of the program, you might want to keep a **static variable**.

```
public class Methods {
     private static int errors = 0;
}
```

Because this is a static variable, it will only be initialized once: when the program begins and the class is loaded.

Also, since you asked for tips to make your code cleaner, instead of

```
 errors = errors + 1;
```

You can use

```
errors++;
```

which has the same effect.

Also, you are currently incrementing **errors** too many times. I see that you are incrementing the variable both inside the **validateMe()** method and also before calling that method. This leads us to the next problem: **you are repeating your entire logic twice!**

You might want to try using a **do-while** loop. For loops, while loops and do-while loops are essentially equivalent in terms of expressive ability.

Here is a rough skeleton:

```
double num1 = 0;
double num2 = 0;

int errors = -1;
do {

    // Increment errors every time you go through the loop.
    // The first time you go through it doesn't really count since we set errors to -1
    errors++;

    if (errors > 0) {
        // If we are here, it's because there was an error
        System.out.println("Error: try again");
    }

    // Here you read a variable with Scanner. Technically you only need one, but I'm reusing your code.
    Scanner a=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter whole number: ");
    num1=a.nextDouble();

    Scanner b=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter whole number: ");
    num2=b.nextDouble();
} while (Math.floor(num1)!=num1 || Math.floor(num2)!=num2);

System.out.println("Great job!");
System.out.println("Addition: "+(num1+num2));
System.out.println("Subtraction: "+(num1-num2));
```

Comment: Thankyou for your help.Since you've veiwed my code,do you think it's efficient?I just wanna make sure I'm not repeating things.

Comment: It's efficient enough, in terms of speed, but it lacks in style. Your for-loop could be made logically cleaner by replacing it with some sort of while loop, which would help you not repeat your entire code twice.

Comment: Technically java doesnt have global variables.

Comment: Edited. You're right, there's a difference between a global variable and a static variable.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways that you can improve this program. For one, you do not need to redefine the Scanner more than once; you can use the same Scanner variable as many times as you need. The second thing is that you should use the validateMe() method in a different way so that you could reuse for multiple purposes.

Here is a different way of doing what you are looking to do:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Methods {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double numberOne;
        double numberTwo;
        System.out.println("This program will both add and subtract two numbers together.\nPlease only use integers.");
        numberOne = getInt();
        numberTwo = getInt();
        System.out.println("Great Job!");
        System.out.println("Addition: "+ (numberOne + numberTwo));
        System.out.println("Subtraction: " + (numberOne - numberTwo));
    }

    public static double getInt() {
        int count = 0;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Please enter a number: ");
        double number = input.nextDouble();
        if (!validateMe(number)) {
            count++;
            return getInt();
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("You have incorrectly entered numbers " + count + " times!");
            return number;
        }
    }

    public static boolean validateMe(double number) {
        if (Math.floor(number) != number) {
            System.out.println("You entered an incorrect number!");
            return false;
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("You entered a correct number!");
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

> Some Other Tips

- I know you are new to programming, but there are some practices you should start to get use to like using even spacing and tabbing so that everything is easier to read. I know that StackOverflow can mess up your formatting, but make sure that you put spaces between things like ***"+"*** to improve the readability of your program.
- When you are creating methods, try to imagine create more methods in ways where they can be used for different purposes to shorten your code.

---

*By no means do you have to use how I created the solution to this problem,*  and that's the best part! You can make your programs the way YOU want! Just try to make it easier on yourself later by shortening code that you reuse by using methods.